# vue route falls into default route while navigation to route with params from same route

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I’m programmatically navigating to this route.

```
{
    path: '/task/:taskId',
    ...
},
```

with this method:

```
itemClick(item) {
    this.$router.push(`task/${item.id}`);
},
```

But when I’m already on route for example http://localhost:port/task/task-1
and call this method. It does not navigate to http://localhost:port/task/task-2
Instead falls into the default route and navigates to http://localhost:port/